# Screen size changed for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have just finished developing a cross platform xamarin app. When I tried to submit my app to apple store there were errors. I think when I was fixing them, I changed something and the screens changed for iOS. Fonts, pictures, keyboard etc.. sizes have grown. It is like the resolution decreased. However there is nothing changed about android side, everything is same. Here are two screen shot  before - after. If you know what is the problem, can you let me know it?

[image: Normal screen]

[image: Last one]

Comment: Did you change some images used in the startup (splash) screen? If your do not have one for each screen size it does this.

Comment: What @James said, from what I know, the way to change the pixel density on iOS devices in Xamarin Forms is to set the proper splash screen image sizes. Don't forget to update Info.plist as well.

Comment: As @James said, the problem was splash screen. I changed it to default and everything fixed. Thanks James!

Answer (score 0):

As James said at comments, the problem was about splash screen. I changed it to default and everything fixed.